# Add multiple aliases to /etc/bash.bashrc aliases if they aren't already there

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

This is how I add multiple aliases to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
cat <<-"BASHRC" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
    alias rss="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service"
    alias brc="nano /etc/bash.bashrc"
    alias www="cd /var/www/html"
    alias imb="bash /opt/imb.sh"
    alias nwsm="bash /opt/nwsm.sh"
BASHRC
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

I feel I could pass on the heredocument and use some other way that would also check if the aliases are already there, is there a simple solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `grep` to check if the line exists, before adding it to `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > /tmp/aliases.tmp << 'BASHRC'
    alias rss='/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service'
    alias brc='nano /etc/bash.bashrc'
    alias www='cd /var/www/html'
    alias imb='bash /opt/imb.sh'
    alias nwsm='bash /opt/nwsm.sh'
BASHRC
for i in `cat /tmp/aliases.tmp`; do
    [[ grep "$i" /etc/bash.bashrc ]] || echo "$i" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
rm /tmp/aliases.tmp
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```